# ZF2 ZfcUser force login

Tags: zend-framework2, php-5.3, zfcuser

I have a ZF2 with module ZfcUser setuped.

Registration and Login forms are working fine. I made a custom module to connect to Linkedin and get the info of a user, then register the user data in the Database.

The register part is done, but the issue I'm facing is that I need to login the user with Data from the Database (I have all the information about the user, so I know what user should be logged in), but I can not find a way to make ZfcUser login a specific user using PHP and not the login form.

I'm not good with the adapters and \Zend\Authentication. I would appreciate any help or directions.

I tried to look at the login procedure in the ZfcUser Controller, but it's confusing me more then helping me.

I also tried looking for the answer in google, but I found nothing on the topic.

If possible, I would like that "forced login procedure" to be outside of the ZfcUser module.

After a few hours of looking at the ZfcUser Controller I managed to build a method to do what i want

```
/**
* Change the currently logged user
* @param integer $user_id
*/
public function setLoggedUser($user_id) {
 $storage = new \Zend\Session\Container('Zend_Auth');
 $storage->storage = $user_id;
}
```

Comment: not sure I follow you here "but I can not find a way to make ZfcUser login a specific user using PHP and not the login form."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the user id directly on your storage has some downsides. It (obviously) won't work if you use another storage engine. And events registered on ZFCUser's `AuthService` will not be executed.

I would solve this issue by using a custom authentication adapter. This Adapter can be called from a controller in the following way:

```
$this->zfcUserAuthentication()->getAuthService()->authenticate(new ForceLogin($user));
```

The implementation looks as follows:

```
class ForceLogin implements Zend\Authentication\Adapter\AdapterInterface
{
    /**
     * @var UserInterface
     */
    protected $user;

    /**
     * @param $user
     */
    function __construct($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function authenticate()
    {
        return new Zend\Authentication\Result(
            Result::SUCCESS,
            $this->getUser()->getId()
        );
    }
}
```